# I want to compile all my *.scss files residing in a folder using web compiler in VS2019

Tags: sass, visual-studio-2019, web-compiler

Is it possible to compile all .scss files residing in a folder using web compiler in Visual Studio 2019?
I don't want to specify each and every file. I tried something like this.

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "wwwroot/assets/css/pages/",
    "inputFile": "wwwroot/assets/sass/pages/**/*.scss",
    "minify": { "enabled": true },
    "includeInProject": true,
    "options": { "sourceMap": true }
  }
]
```

Comment: Ever figure this out? Trying to do the same thing.